# Getting data quality in Delta Live Table (bronze, gold, silver..)

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

How to check if Delta Live Table is in bronze, gold or silver layer(zone) with python? I have notebook for creating Delta Live Table pipeline, and I need to know what is quality of data(silver, bronze, gold). How to get that information with python?

In SQL exist something like `TBLPROPERTIES('BRONZE')`, is there anything like that for python?

Comment: who adds these table properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@dlt.table(
  comment="Bronze live streaming table for Test data",
  name="bronze_test_table",
  table_properties={
    "quality": "bronze"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sql solution run it directly with

```py
spark.sql('''SHOW TBLPROPERTIES table_name'')
```